# For Loop Not Passing Id Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to pass the res[i].id to my ArrayList and i want the result will be in sequence. anyone know how the other 809 and 806. is not patching in the arrayList

```
0: {id: 0, ArrayListID: 809, VarName: "TEST001A"}
1: {id: 0, ArrayListID: 806, VarName: "TEST002A"}
2: {id: 0, ArrayListID: 0, VarName: "TEST001B"}         //result
3: {id: 0, ArrayListID: 0, VarName: "TEST002B"}


809
809    // here is the res[i].id 
806
806


varName:any[] = [];

postTesting(){
  this.serv.postTest(this.fg.value?.dRay).subscribe((res:any[])=>{
    console.log(res)
    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
      this.varName[i].ArrayListID = res[i].id
    }

    this.serv.postTest1(this.varName).subscribe((r)=> {
      console.log()
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Using double nested subscriptions is a bad idea, and not unsubscribing can cause memory leaks. Use pipes instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, I think you may have the assignment the wrong way around?

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.res.length; i++){
  res[i].id = this.varName[i].ArrayListID
}
```

should be

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.res.length; i++){
  this.varName[i].ArrayListID = res[i].id
}
```

This will then allow you to provide an updated `this.varName` to your `serv.postTest1` call. Currently you are assigning data **from** `this.varName` **to** your temporary variable `res` so `this.varName` remains unchanged.

*Note: As @churill recommended yesterday, it would be worth reading up on avoiding nested subscribes* https://www.thinktecture.com/en/angular/rxjs-antipattern-1-nested-subs/

Comment: I already tried this one but I'm having the same output.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is I'm afraid. Could you maybe expand your question in more detail to describe what you are expecting and what is happening, and what you have tried already?

Comment: the problem is i cant pass the res[i].id to the ArrayListID sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

you're using this.res.length for response,
try using res.length

```
for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
   this.varName[i].ArrayListID = res[i].id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear as to what exactly your code is doing ... specifically what the postTest methods are returning.

But something like this may work:

```
    this.generateIds()
      .pipe(
        map((ids) => {
          var index = -1;
          return ids.map((id) => { 
            index += 1;
            return { ...testData[index], ArrayListId: id }});
        })
      )
      .subscribe((result) => console.log('result', JSON.stringify(result)));
  }
```

The `generateIds()` is meant to be this: `this.serv.postTest(this.fg.value?.dRay)` ... assuming that is what that method is returning.

The code then uses the `pipe` to process the emitted array of ids. Assume that the ids are returned as an array.

The `map` then transforms the array of ids into an array of data using those ids as the `ArrayListId`.

Inside the map, the `ids.map` processes each entry in the array of ids. For each one, it maps it to a new object with the original object properties plus the new ArrayListId property with it's value.

The result is:

```
[{"id":0,"VarName":"TEST001A","ArrayListId":809},
{"id":0,"VarName":"TEST002A","ArrayListId":809},
{"id":0,"VarName":"TEST001B","ArrayListId":806},
{"id":0,"VarName":"TEST002B","ArrayListId":806}]
```

Is that close to what you are trying to do?

Also, as others have said, it's best to avoid nested subscriptions. For more information, check out this video: https://youtu.be/KiJ-e5QuWe4